# Altair / Streamlit: Is there any way to retrieve the value from a selection?

Tags: python, interactive, streamlit, altair

I am creating a web app with charts. If one hovers (and clicks) on a chart, I want to display more information about that element below (i.e. outside of) that chart. Currently, I am using the following to highlight a specific bar in the chart.

```
single = alt.selection_single(on="click"

c = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar.encode(
    ...
).add_selection(single)
```

Can I further use the information *which* bar is being clicked on?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565901/how-to-retrieve-attributes-from-selected-datum-in-altair)?

Comment: Thanks! I have seen it, but didn't quite understand the mechanics.

Comment: The streamlit [package](https://github.com/domoritz/streamlit-vega-lite) package looks straightforward. If you are looking for Altair specific solution without streamlit, I am not sure if that is possible at the moment. Let's see if someone else can show us how to do it.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. So this is exactly what I need. But I somehow can't install it. I ran pip but Streamlit can't find it `No module named 'streamlit_vega_lite'`. Do I assume correctly that I have to run the `Dev Setup` part?

Comment: I installed it successfully on Python 3.10 with pip version 22.2.2. Check if the pip is up to date. Otherwise, I think the module creator could help you better regarding the installation issue.

Comment: Installation worked. I implemented the example in my streamlit code but it doesn't write anything. If I select something in the chart, the page just refreshes and a new random histogram appears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are created the second chart with Altair, then you can use the information about which bar is clicked in that second chart. Example here [Altair choropleth map, color highlight based on line chart selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751130/altair-choropleth-map-color-highlight-based-on-line-chart-selection/65948144#65948144)

Altair cannot send the information of which bar has been clicked on outside of Altair. If you want to do that, you need to use a package that is able to retrieve this info from Altair/VegaLite on its own. Currently, the only robust solution for this is via Panel, you can read more in this issue https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1153

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and thorough answer! I am gonna look into that.